# how can I read all the text files contents from the document's Directory in an android device from external storage

Tags: android

Thank you @Sam Chen your link was helpful. I was able to solve problem number 1 . I was able to read , write and overwrite a single text file .

Problem that I am facing:-

1. I want to read the contents of all the text files present in (/storage/emulated/0/Documents/Password/) directory but I am not able to do so.

here is the code for writing the text file int the directory

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String File_NAME="Password.txt";
EditText editText;
TextView textView2;
Button open_file;
Button save_file;
Button get_all_files;

//Strings related to file name and file directory
String FileName="";
String FileContent = "";

// After API 23 the permission request for accessing external storage is changed
// Before API 23 permission request is asked by the user during installation of app
// After API 23 permission request is asked at runtime
private int EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 23;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.EditText);
    textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    save_file=findViewById(R.id.save);
    open_file = findViewById(R.id.open);
    get_all_files = findViewById(R.id.get_all_files);

    // Requesting Permission to access External Storage
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);

    //initialize two String variables for storing file name and file path
    FileName = "Password.txt";

    save_file.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FileContent = editText.getText().toString();
            try {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "Password");       //file name
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "text/plain");        //file extension, will automatically add to file
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/Password/");     //end "/" is not mandatory

                Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), values);      //important! external storage

                OutputStream outputStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);

                //FileContent String contains the text content of the file
                outputStream.write(FileContent.getBytes());

                outputStream.close();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File created successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail to create file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

here is the code I wrote to read all the text files in the above mentioned directory
creating a list that will hold the list of text files present in the custom directory external_storage/Documents/Password

```
ArrayList<File> inFiles = new ArrayList<File>();

    get_all_files.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                File externalStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS); //getting external storage directory
                //it's another method to get the directory of a file inside the external storage of a device
                File folder = new File(externalStorageDirectory + "/Password");
                File file[] = folder.listFiles();
                if (file.length != 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
                        //here populate your list
                        inFiles.add(file[i]);

                    }
                } else {
                    //no file available
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            //checking if th inFiles list is populated or not
            //this list will store the list of files with their directory location
            Log.i("list", inFiles.toString());
```

now we can extract file names and their contents

```
for (int l = 0; l < inFiles.size(); l++) {
                String jsonString="";
                //file_name: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/Password/Password.txt it store the entire directory as a string
                String file_directory = inFiles.get(l).toString() + "\n";
                Log.i("file_directory", file_directory);

                //now we can extract the file name from the extracted file's directory
                // create object of Path
                Path path = Paths.get(file_directory);

                // call getFileName() and get FileName path object
                //Path fileName contains the name of the file
                Path fileNamePath = path.getFileName();

                Log.i("file_name", fileNamePath.toString());
```

now here we can use URI to read files from the documents directory

```
Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");

                String selection = MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH + "=?";

                String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/Password/"};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, selection, selectionArgs, null);

                Uri uri = null;

                if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No file found in \"" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/Password/\"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    String fileName2 = fileNamePath.toString();
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        String fileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        Log.i("file_name_uri", fileName);
                        Log.i("file_name2",fileName2);

                        //it should break when fileName = fileName2 but it's not breaking the loop when I am comparing fileName with another string variable fileName2
                        //but it is working just file if i pass direct file name directly for example if(fileName.equals("Password.txt"))
                        if (fileName.equals(fileName2))
                        {
                            long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));

                            uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(contentUri, id);

                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (uri == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "\"Password.txt\" not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        try {
                            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

                            int size = inputStream.available();

                            byte[] bytes = new byte[size];

                            inputStream.read(bytes);

                            inputStream.close();

                            jsonString = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

                            Log.i("file_content",jsonString);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail to read file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }



            }

    });
```

here is my log output:-

```
2021-06-10 15:05:58.312 14317-14317/? I/ya.neomorphicu: Unquickening 19 vdex files!

2021-06-10 15:06:01.199 14317-14317/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_directory: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/Password/Password.txt

2021-06-10 15:06:01.199 14317-14317/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name: Password.txt

2021-06-10 15:06:01.248 14317-14317/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name_uri: Password.txt

2021-06-10 15:06:01.248 14317-14317/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name2: Password.txt

2021-06-10 15:06:01.248 14317-14317/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name_uri: Password (1).txt

2021-06-10 15:06:01.248 14317-14317/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name2: Password.txt

2021-06-10 15:06:01.248 14317-14317/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name_uri: Password (2).txt

2021-06-10 15:06:01.248 14317-14317/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name2: Password.txt

2021-06-10 15:06:01.294 14317-14317/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_directory: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/Password/Password (1).txt

2021-06-10 15:06:01.295 14317-14317/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name: Password (1).txt

2021-06-10 15:06:01.307 14317-14317/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name_uri: Password.txt

2021-06-10 15:06:01.307 14317-14317/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name2: Password (1).txt

2021-06-10 15:06:01.307 14317-14317/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name_uri: Password (1).txt

2021-06-10 15:06:01.307 14317-14317/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name2: Password (1).txt

2021-06-10 15:06:01.307 14317-14317/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name_uri: Password (2).txt

2021-06-10 15:06:01.307 14317-14317/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name2: Password (1).txt

2021-06-10 15:06:01.322 14317-14317/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_directory: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/Password/Password (2).txt

2021-06-10 15:06:01.323 14317-14317/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name: Password (2).txt

2021-06-10 15:06:01.337 14317-14317/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name_uri: Password.txt

2021-06-10 15:06:01.337 14317-14317/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name2: Password (2).txt

2021-06-10 15:06:01.337 14317-14317/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name_uri: Password (1).txt

2021-06-10 15:06:01.337 14317-14317/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name2: Password (2).txt

2021-06-10 15:06:01.337 14317-14317/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name_uri: Password (2).txt

2021-06-10 15:06:01.337 14317-14317/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name2: Password (2).txt
```

but when I replace if (fileName.equals(fileName2)) with if (fileName.equals("Password (1).txt")) in here:-

```
 //it should break when fileName = fileName2 but it's not breaking the loop when I am comparing fileName with another string variable fileName2
                        //but it is working just file if i pass direct file name directly for example if(fileName.equals("Password.txt"))
                        if (fileName.equals("Password (1).txt"))
                        {
                            long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));

                            uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(contentUri, id);

                            break;
                        }
                    }
```

The Log output starts giving the content of Password (1).txt
how can I get the contents of all the text Files present int this directory

Here is my Log output:-

```
2021-06-10 15:12:42.657 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_directory: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/Password/Password.txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.658 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name: Password.txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.679 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name_uri: Password.txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.679 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name2: Password.txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.679 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name_uri: Password (1).txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.679 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name2: Password.txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.692 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_content: hello human

2021-06-10 15:12:42.692 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_directory: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/Password/Password (1).txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.693 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name: Password (1).txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.713 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name_uri: Password.txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.713 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name2: Password (1).txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.713 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name_uri: Password (1).txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.714 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name2: Password (1).txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.725 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_content: hello human

2021-06-10 15:12:42.725 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_directory: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/Password/Password (2).txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.725 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name: Password (2).txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.738 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name_uri: Password.txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.738 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name2: Password (2).txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.738 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name_uri: Password (1).txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.738 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name2: Password (2).txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.747 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_content: hello human

2021-06-10 15:12:42.747 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_directory: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/Password/Password.txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.747 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name: Password.txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.758 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name_uri: Password.txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.758 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name2: Password.txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.758 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name_uri: Password (1).txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.758 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name2: Password.txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.765 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_content: hello human

2021-06-10 15:12:42.765 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_directory: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/Password/Password (1).txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.765 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name: Password (1).txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.775 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name_uri: Password.txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.775 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name2: Password (1).txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.775 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name_uri: Password (1).txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.775 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name2: Password (1).txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.782 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_content: hello human

2021-06-10 15:12:42.782 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_directory: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/Password/Password (2).txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.782 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name: Password (2).txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.792 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name_uri: Password.txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.792 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name2: Password (2).txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.792 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name_uri: Password (1).txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.792 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name2: Password (2).txt

2021-06-10 15:12:42.800 18427-18427/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_content: hello human
```

here is the code which was requested by @blackapps
the code below only gets the content of a single text file from the documents folder in the shared external storage .

```
open_file.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"); //tells which storage device is to be used

                String selection = MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH + "=?";

                String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/Password/"};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, selection, selectionArgs, null);

                Uri uri = null;

                if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No file found in \"" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/Password/\"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        String fileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                      //implement  for loop to read the multiple Passwords text file
                        if (fileName.equals("Password (1).txt")) {
                            long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));

                            uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(contentUri, id);

                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (uri == null) {
                        //implement  for loop to read the multiple Passwords text file
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "\"Password.txt\" not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        try {
                            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

                            int size = inputStream.available();

                            byte[] bytes = new byte[size];

                            inputStream.read(bytes); //this will read the contents of the text file line by line

                            inputStream.close();

                            String jsonString = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); //this will store the read contents in string format of Password.txt file
                            textView2.setText(jsonString);
                            Log.i("content_of_text_file",jsonString);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail to read file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

just to make things clear there are 3 buttons in this app

1. save_file button which saves the file (working)
2. open_file button which only opens the file that is passed in
   if (fileName.equals("Password (1).txt")) (working)
3. get_all_files which is supposed to get the contents of all the saved text files from the documents folder.(not working yet)

here is my Log output when i pressed open_file button:-

```
2021-06-11 14:44:52.640 15540-15540/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/content_of_text_file: hello human
```

@blackapps Sir I Changed my code because you said that "You had those File instances so you could read content of every file already" But the problem still remains Also I used URI because this method did not work earlier I used this method before using URI
here is my updated code:-

```
//now here we can read files from the documents directory
                    File file = new File(file_directory);
                    String data = getdata(file);
                    if (data != null) {
                        Log.i("file_content",data);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File not found!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
```

the function for getting data

```
private String getdata(File myfile) {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(myfile);
            int i = -1;
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while ((i = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
                buffer.append((char) i);
            }
            return buffer.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fileInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    fileInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

here is my Log output:-

```
2021-06-11 15:29:18.209 16606-16606/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_directory: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/Password/Password.txt

2021-06-11 15:29:18.209 16606-16606/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name: Password.txt

2021-06-11 15:29:18.210 16606-16606/com.aditya.neomorphicui W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/Password/Password.txt

2021-06-11 15:29:18.210 16606-16606/com.aditya.neomorphicui W/System.err: : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

2021-06-11 15:29:18.212 16606-16606/com.aditya.neomorphicui W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:160)

2021-06-11 15:29:18.214 16606-16606/com.aditya.neomorphicui W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

2021-06-11 15:29:18.233 16606-16606/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_directory: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/Password/Password (1).txt

2021-06-11 15:29:18.233 16606-16606/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name: Password (1).txt

2021-06-11 15:29:18.234 16606-16606/com.aditya.neomorphicui W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/Password/Password (1).txt

2021-06-11 15:29:18.234 16606-16606/com.aditya.neomorphicui W/System.err: : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

2021-06-11 15:29:18.234 16606-16606/com.aditya.neomorphicui W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:160)

2021-06-11 15:29:18.235 16606-16606/com.aditya.neomorphicui W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

2021-06-11 15:29:18.247 16606-16606/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_directory: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/Password/Password (2).txt

2021-06-11 15:29:18.247 16606-16606/com.aditya.neomorphicui I/file_name: Password (2).txt

2021-06-11 15:29:18.248 16606-16606/com.aditya.neomorphicui W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/Password/Password (2).txt

2021-06-11 15:29:18.248 16606-16606/com.aditya.neomorphicui W/System.err: : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

2021-06-11 15:29:18.248 16606-16606/com.aditya.neomorphicui W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:160)

2021-06-11 15:29:18.250 16606-16606/com.aditya.neomorphicui W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: `now we can extract file names and their contents` Well you dont need the names but you could read the content of every file. But you are not doing that.

Comment: `now here we can use URI to read files from the documents directory` ???? What are you talking about? You should be ready by now. No need for uries. You had those File instances so you could read content of every file already. I understand norhing... And suddenly the media store comes in? Not needed all that stuff

Comment: Please post the code for a function that given a File instance returns the content of that file as a String.

Comment: Not as comment as code in comments is unreadable. Just add a nice code block to your post.

Comment: @ blackcaps Sir said "You had those File instances so you could read content of every file already" . Can you please point out in my code where is the problem with a correction and post your answer below . Like I said I am a total noob in android dev.

Comment: @blackapps Thank you sir I will take note of it.

Comment: @blackapps Sir I have added the code that you've asked for Please take a look at it. Thank you Sir for Answering my questions. I am really grateful

Comment: ?????? You just reposted a bunch of code. We had already seen that.  Why do you post your code twice? And it does not look like the code i asked for.

Comment: @blackapps This is all the code there is Sir.

Comment: Ok. But i asked you to program that function. Now why didnt you?

Comment: @blackapps Sir I am well aware that the problem lies here "File file = new File(file_directory);" because when I pass the directory in "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/Password/Password (2).txt" it reads the contents of the text file just fine